# Get standalone exe file from pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Please do note that I still am new to pyinstaller.

I know how to turn a python file into an exe file. The problem is, whenever I enter: `pyinstaller --onefile *[Your File Here]*` into the command prompt, it doesn't seem to work and instead creates a bunch of files.

Comment: Does the documentation give any hints? Have you found any previous SO Q&A's  on the subject but they didn't work?

Comment: I Rewatched the tutorial i was following and sure enough, it works. Anyways thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onefile option flag will create a one-file bundled executable, see [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html?highlight=onefile#what-to-generate). When you invoke the pyinstaller command you mentioned, it will generate a directory called dist where you could find the executable YourFile.exe there.

Try

```
cd dist
```

then

```
ls
```

Can you see the executable there?

Comment: Yes, the executable is there, thanks :)